# How to set "Go to address" to open the address in a new tab in safari

Tags: macos, safari

I am a new Safari user, and I want the browser to open a new tab instead of the current tab when I select an address and click "Go to address", just like in Chrome. Can I achieve this without plugin?

Comment: Sorry, actually there is  a `Go to address in new Tab` entry in the context menu, and I just ignored it. What a stupid question.

Comment: I edited `your` question. `Safari`, `Chrome` and buttons ARE NOT CODE. Superfluous `code` makes `your` post `hard` to read

Answer (score 2):

You can use added hot-keys to make a whole set of different actions happen when you click a link.

This is the way I have mine set in Safari Preferences…

[image]

This way, a simple click will open the link in the current page,
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> /click will open it in a new Tab but not activate it &
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> /click will open it in a new Tab & also bring it to the front.

Setting the first dropmenu to 'Always' will also set a new Tab to be opened if you select the URL in another application & right-click select 'Open URL'

Comment: My question is about plain text address, not the one in `<a />` tag. Anyway, I found out that there is an entry just next to the `Go to address`. I made a stupid mistake.